# Dimensional modeling for dynamic tree relational structures

Tags: tree, business-intelligence, olap, olap-cube, dimensional-modeling

I am planning to render a database which relates several nodes parenthood in an E/R fashion as an OLAP cube. My model contemplates a tree which needs to be dynamic, configurable.

In order to end up with a dimensional representation of the database, I have to convert my E/R database to an star schema, and the natural way to represent my tree is by mapping it to a dimensional hierarchy.

My problem comes when that dynamic tree needs to be configurable, as for now, I can only conclude that every time that tree changes, the whole dimension table needs to be denormalized according to the new tree schema

```
   **FACT_TABLE**            **DIM_TABLE**
   DIM_TREE   METRIC                   NODE_LEVEL1   NODE_LEVEL2     NODE_LEVEL3 
   dim_id  leaf1_value       dim_id1   root_1        intermediate_1  leaf_1
   dim_id2 leaf2_value       dim_id2   root_1                        leaf_2
```

What if I want to change the tree structure (i.e, add a level, change its semantic meaning...)?
Do I have to change dimensional schema again to define new fields and hierarchies?

In addition, sometimes I am asked to provide several logical trees that map sets of common leafs. That means that either I create a new dimension for the new logical aggregation or I denormalize it within DIM_TABLE. In both cases, I need to modify schema and I break the granularity, as the value is counted as many times as aggregation trees reference it. Am I right?

Is dimensional/OLAP modeling suitable for those requirements? If so, what's the best approach aside from modeling a db schema for every aggregation tree and changing hierarchy/taxonomy?

Comment: How often your tree changes? Is it practical to compute everything again at every change? I work with threes using father/parent nodes (lets say tree-table) and relate my dimensions on table like Node-DimId-Value for each node. The whole three changes monthly.

Comment: This question is from a few months ago - did you resolve the issue yourself, or do you still need an answer?

Comment: I moved from project.. I even offered a bounty at thattime but no one wnswered iwthin the bounty period, but thanks for the interest. If you have any interesting and deep insight, I am still open to accept an answer.